# how to detect if the activity was opened by another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity called `FooActivity`. It can be opened two ways. 1 - by `MainActivity` and 2 - by going to my app's URL

In the `doInBackground(..)` of `AsyncTask` in `FooActivity` I have the following code to finish this activity.

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(FooActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
returnIntent.putExtra("result", "one");
AcceptActivity.this.setResult(FooActivity.this.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
AcceptActivity.this.finish();
```

This works fine when my app had already been opened. Because when I finish `FooActivity` I would see `MainActivity`.

However, if my app was not already opened and the first time it opened was through a URL, then `FooActivity` just finishes and I see the phone's desktop.

**Question**

Is there a way to detect whether `MainActivity` has been opened already or not? If it is not opened then I'd change above code to open the `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do that in your onPostExecute() of your FooActivity

launch home screen using `startActivity(Intent)` with an intent that has flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, and pass the result manually through the intent

Comment: what will that do? I'm not pressing the back button

Comment: I'm sorry i misunderstood your question, i've edited my answer